# Merge Sort for characters

Tags: arrays, performance, sorting, mergesort

I have a large array of pointers, say 15,000 of them.

I have a small bit of code

```
for (int x = 0; x < n;x++)
{
    mergeSort(array[x],0,strlen(array[x]-1);
}
```

The reason I put merge sort in loop like that is to sort the characters in each index in alphabetical order, not the strings in the array.

Is this losing efficiency if I have merge sort in the for loop? Will it make me lose run time of n log n?

Comment: This sounds like an [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you want to sort the characters of each string in an array of strings, then this is fine. For example "apple", "hello" is turned to "aelpp", "ehllo". But I suspect that's not your ultimate goal.

Comment: I'm wondering the same as @janos. Perhaps the goal is to use mergesort to sort the array of 15,000 pointers to strings, not to sort 15,000 strings. You didn't post the code for mergesort(), so we can't tell if it's an optimal implementation of merge sort.

Answer (score 0):

If we take `k` as total number of letters, the time would be `n*k/n*log(k/n) = k*log(k/n)`. It would be even faster than if You had all characters in one array and sort them all (that would be `k*log(k)`). There is no way to do it asymptotically better.

From practical point of view, You may consider

- Using different sorting method. While asymptotically equivalent, some methods may perform better on short arrays (due to better memory locality for example, have a look here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHNmRkzxHWs&t=52m36s).
- Using multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

Merge sort is always `O(n * log_2(n))`, where `n` is the length of the array being sorted. In this case, that's the string length. Each sort will be `O(n * log_2(n))`.

However, you're repeating the sort once for each of the strings, thus the total time is the sum of the time for each string:

```
O(n1 * log_2(n1)) + O(n2 * log_2(n2)) + ... + O(nk * log_2(nk))
```

Where n1, n2, ..., nk are the lengths of all of the `k` strings being sorted.

If we assume that all `k` strings have length `n`, than this algorithm as a whole is `k * O(n * log_2(n))`.

Comment: Thank you that helps alot. I am comparing words and the fastest run time is to sort and compare. I am still not sure why my code is being slower then brute force. In brute force, I have k * O (n^2) where n is the size of the word. I have tried input size of 1,000,000 but still O(n^2) is taking shorter amount of time

Comment: Keep in mind that all these time complexities are asymptotic, that is, they represent the behavior as n approaches infinity. It's quite common to have `O(n^2)` algorithms that perform faster than `O(n * log_2(n))` for small values of n.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can do better then O(n log n) by using some type of radix sort.

For example, if all characters are 1 byte you can do the following (unless the strings are really short):

```
create an array of 256 ints
for each string:
    memset array to 0 (*)
    loop through the bytes until zero is reached
        for each byte increment the corresponding value in the array
    loop through the array and write n characters with the value of current pos
     (*) instead of memset, you could reset the values to zero in this loop
```

This also eliminates the call to `strlen()`, which has to scan the full string to get the length. So you're doing the sort with a single pass through your string.

If your strings only contain regular characters and digits, a shorter array can be used.

If the strings are really short, the above and other sorting algorithms will have some overhead. Instead you could do a test with bubblesort (yes) - I read somewhere that for a small number of items bubblesort can be faster (I think the number was around 6).

Of course, if the strings are unicode, you'll have to do some more work (but it doesn't look that way looking at the example code).

Comment: All that stuff about “plain text = ascii = characters are 8 bits” is not only wrong, it’s hopelessly wrong, and if you’re still programming that way, you’re not much better than a medical doctor who doesn’t believe in germs. https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Well actually I had typed in some text concerning unicode, but removed it again before posting to keep the answer simple, because the question/answer is more about algorithm then about unicode, and the code in the question seems to work with single bytes as well. Anyway, sorting an array of unicode characters (or an utf-8 string) using standard sorting algorithms would always be a problem because characters can be encoded in a different number of bytes (even UTF-16), or need to be combined into one. Btw, interesting link, I've read that article multiple times in the past.

Comment: I absolutely agree with You, I was just missing this part in the original answer. There is so much software that can not deal with localized strings, this evil has to be rooted out. If people see char->8bit in every code they learn it is no wonder they use it in production code later.